# Unrecognized Option in subprocess.run()

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to run this command `ebsynth -style source_photo.png -guide source_segment.png target_segment.png -output output.png`.

This works perfectly in cmd but not in python subprocess.run()

Python Code

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.run([
    'ebsynth',
    '-style', 'source_photo.png',
    '-guide', 'source_segment.png target_segment.png',
    '-output', 'output.png'
  ], shell=True, cwd=dir)
```

Running this I am getting `error: unrecognized option 'output.png'`

What is the problem?

Comment: `shell=True` is an additional problem, at least assuming you're trying to run this on POSIX-compliant operating systems. With `shell=True` and providing an argument list rather than a single string, your list gets appended to `['sh', '-c']`, so only the _first_ list element is code; the second list element is `$0` in the context that code is run, the third is `$1`, etc. If the code in the first array element never refers to `$0`, `$1`, `$@` &c, then the other arguments are just ignored; the easy fix for this is to stick to the default `shell=False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ebsynth` expects two filenames after the `-guide` option, but you're passing those two filenames as a single string, so it's using `'source_segment.png target_segment.png'` as the first filename and `'-output'` as the second, causing `output.png` to be an unexpected option.

Try separating the filenames, like this:

```
process = subprocess.run(['ebsynth', '-style', 'source_photo.png', '-guide', 'source_segment.png', 'target_segment.png', '-output', 'output.png'], shell=True, cwd=dir)
```

Comment: Yes, you found it right. I was getting error `error: failed to load 'source_segment.png target_segment.png'
can't fopen`.